# Unable to install library react-image-annotate

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

I am trying to install react-image-annotate but receiving the below error

```
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\lenovo\.windows-build- 
tools\python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\EnFuse_Project_Folder\\annotationBoundingBox\\two\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-G',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs_version=2015',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\\EnFuse_Project_Folder\\annotationBoundingBox\\two\\node_modules\\canvas\\build\\config.gypi',
```

npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\EnFuse_Project_Folder\annotationBoundingBox\two\node_modules\node-gyp\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\Users\lenovo\.node-gyp\17.9.1\include\node\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\Users\lenovo\.node-gyp\17.9.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=D:\EnFuse_Project_Folder\annotationBoundingBox\two\node_modules\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\Users\lenovo\.node-gyp\17.9.1\<(target_arch)\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=D:\EnFuse_Project_Folder\annotationBoundingBox\two\node_modules\canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'D:\EnFuse_Project_Folder\annotationBoundingBox\two\node_modules\canvas\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build/binding.sln',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/nologo',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.9.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v4.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

Comment: did yo find the solution? I am struck in the same problem